# Calculating Time Difference Between pairs of rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have database records like this:

```
Connected                 UpdatedTime
1                         2015-02-05 13:13:23.420
0                         2015-02-05 23:40:50.360
1                         2015-02-05 23:40:50.357
0                         2015-02-05 23:34:41.250
```

`1` is when I connect external device to pc and `0` is when I disconnect it.
I want to find how many seconds usb device was connected and how many seconds it was disconnected.

My Question:

Can I do that using MSSQL Query?

Comment: which version of sql-server are you running ? What did you try ?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2, I dont know how to do it. Only thing i know to use "DATEDIFF()" like "lolund" said. I know only simple queries. Like this :SELECT  DATEDIFF(second, UpdatedDate, UpdatedDate)

Comment: The version is very important information. Now the **LEAD** answer i was writing is useless. I assume Connected is a bit

Comment: With SQL 2008 I'd recommend doing this in the middleware, or else with a stored procedure - there's no clean way to do this otherwise. If you have the option to go to SQL 2012 you can use an analytical query with the `LAG` / `LEAD` functions, which works very nicely in cases like this.

Comment: Sorry, i should have mentioned version in question. And also i just noticed, i messed up with times. But in my db it is properly arranged like disconnect time is after connect time.

Comment: @Ed Gibbs: I was trying this in hibernate. But could not find how i skip one row after calculating time diff. As i need to calculate in pairs starting from '1'.

Comment: Rajkishan: I don't know much about nHibernate so I can't help there. As for the downvote, it wasn't me but I suspect it's because you didn't show what you've tried so far. I'm not so picky about that. Don't be discouraged; I see you've gotten an answer and that's the main thing.

Comment: Yes you are right! It is just that, i saw negative vote and wrote some random stuff. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tweaked the values to make the result more meaningful (and verifiable) than the thousands of seconds in your sample data. I've used a self-joining recursive cte to perform the `DATEDIFF` calculations, like so:

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44165/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE USBConnections
    ([Connected] int, [UpdatedTime] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO USBConnections
    ([Connected], [UpdatedTime])
VALUES
    (1, '2015-02-05 13:00:00'),
    (0, '2015-02-05 13:00:50'),
    (1, '2015-02-05 14:00:50'),
    (0, '2015-02-05 14:00:55')
;
```

**Query 1**:

Note the recursive cte joins to itself based on the row number being `-1` less than the current row and the status having switched between `1` and `0`.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT [Connected], [UpdatedTime], 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [UpdatedTime]) rownum
FROM USBConnections
)
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, cte1.[UpdatedTime], cte2.[UpdatedTime]) ) ConnectedTime
FROM    cte cte1
INNER JOIN cte cte2 ON cte1.rownum = cte2.rownum - 1 
      AND (cte1.Connected = 1 AND cte2.Connected = 0)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44165/1/0)**:

```
| CONNECTEDTIME |
|---------------|
|            55 |
```

**Reference:**

### [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions (CTE)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Wow, it works for showing connected time. Can i get disconnecttime also in same query or i have to write a new one? And for the first time i am seeing query like this.:) Do you have a good reference from where i can learn more on queries like this?

Comment: if you switch the last part of the join around it _should_ work out the disconnected time: `AND (cte1.Connected = 0 AND cte2.Connected = 1)`

Comment: I cannot, it says not enough reputation.

Comment: @Rajkishan ah yes, you need to get to 15 rep before you can vote.